# when inserting data with gorm, the check does not exist the same

Tags: sql, go, go-gorm

I am using gorm. I want to insert value while not exist same value

just like the raw sql.

```sql
INSERT INTO student (firstname, lastname)
SELECT 'NEW FIRSTNAME', 'NEW LASTNAME'
FROM DUAL
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT 1
    FROM table_name
    WHERE firstname = 'NEW FIRSTNAME' AND lastname = 'NEW LASTNAME'
)
LIMIT 1;
```

How to implement this function with gorm

```golang
type Student struct {
    Firstname string
    Lastname string
}

func insert()  {
    stu :=Student{"fir","la"}
    if res := DB.Create(&stu).Or("some condition"); res.Error != nil {
        logrus.Println(res.Error)

    }
}
```

when found same value i want a message or error message

Answer (score 1):

[FirstOrCreate](http://jinzhu.me/gorm/crud.html#firstorcreate)

Get first matched record, or initalize a new one with given conditions (only works with struct, map conditions)

```
db.FirstOrCreate(&user, User{Name: "non_existing"})
```